# Div's Overlapping on Window Resize

Tags: css, html

I can't keep the navigation bar links and the header from moving when the page is resized. 
I have tried putting everything in a wrapper div but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the link to the page: http://www.public.asu.edu/~rmtorren/broadway.html

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're giving the navigation links an *absolute* width. Therefore, when the window becomes smaller the links are not shrinking proportionately. Consider using percentages, or setting different widths using [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

The style causing the issue is:

```
#navigation ul a:link {
padding: 5px 5px 15px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
display: block;
width: 100px;         /* CHANGE THIS */
text-decoration: none;
background-color: maroon;
color: #FFF;
}
```

An example of a media query could be:

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
    #navigation ul a:link {
        width: 60px;
    }
}
```

The above will change the links to be only `60 pixels` if the screen shrinks below `768px`

Comment: Awesome that fixed the side bar beautifully. Thanks so much that was giving me a headache.